# Accessing a method in the same factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory defined like this:

```
mob.factory("OrderHelper", function() {
    return {
      lineItemPrice: function(lineItem) {
        return lineItem.price * lineItem.quantity;
      },
      orderTotal: function(order) {
        order.items.forEach(function (item)) {
          total += lineItemPrice(item);
        }
      }
    }
});
```

That problem is that I can't use the method "lineItemPrice" in "orderTotal" method.
It throws this error: Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: £{{orderTotal(order)}}
Can somebody please tell how can I call a method from a function in the same factory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could also do it like this:

```
mob.factory("OrderHelper", function() {
    var methods = {};

    methods.lineItemPrice = function(lineItem) {
      return lineItem.price * lineItem.quantity;
    };

    methods.orderTotal = function(order) {
      order.items.forEach(function (item)) {
        total += methods.lineItemPrice(item);
      }
    };

    return methods;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this (the [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)):

```
mob.factory("OrderHelper", function() {
    var lineItemPrice = function(lineItem) {
      return lineItem.price * lineItem.quantity;
    };

    var orderTotal = function(order) {
      order.items.forEach(function (item)) {
        total += lineItemPrice(item);
      }
    };

    return {
      lineItemPrice: lineItemPrice,
      orderTotal: orderTotal
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.foreach() to iterate each items and supply the third parameter as the context of the callback function.

```
mob.factory("OrderHelper", function() {
    return {
      lineItemPrice: function(lineItem) {
        return lineItem.price * lineItem.quantity;
      },
      orderTotal: function(order) {
        var total = 0;

        angular.forEach(order.items, function(item) {
          total += this.lineItemPrice(item)
        }, this); // add `this` as the context of the callback

        return total;
      }
    }
});
```